# Adobe Air Mobile: Touch to the Components

Tags: flash, air, touch

Im wanna create app use Flash Professional.

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;         
addBtn.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, addFunction);
```

With this code, im use event listener. But, offical component is not sensitive. They are not affecting from touch event. What should i do?